# Intellisense not working when trying to define an xmlns in VS2012

Tags: wpf, xaml, intellisense, xml-namespaces

I am trying to add a namespace to one of my usercontrols in xaml. In visual studio 2010 I could just type `xmlns:blahblah=` and it would add the quotations and offer me a whole list of suggestions of assemblies to add as namespace definitions.

In visual studio 2012 I start typing it out and I'm immediately getting xaml errors as I'm typing and no suggestions. The problem is, I don't know what the exact ones I need to add, so I'm a little dependent on the intellisense.

Regular intellisense works just fine. Why is this?

[image]

Comment: Just facing same problem. By closing and reopening Visual Studio it is working again.

Comment: I wish I could say that restarting visual studio fixes this for me, but it is not. Occasionally the regular intellisense in visual studio stops working, and a restart fixes that, but not the namespace intellisense that shows me all of the assemblies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have been the fact that I was using `.NET 4.0 Client Profile` for my application. I went ahead and transferred it over to `.NET 4.5`(full), but I am sure `.NET 4.0`(full) would work just as well. It seemed to have fixed nearly all of the intellisense problems I've been having.

I don't know what the downsides are to switching will be, though for 4.5 there isn't even a `Client Profile` version