# WPF namespace not working with intellisense

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, intellisense

I am trying to set up a WPF application with a user control library. The library is in .NET 4.5, as is my project. I have set a namespace (xmlns:blah) of `"clr-namespace:Fluent;assembly=Fluent"` in MainWindow.xaml. I am using VS2012. I have had this work before about a year ago, but I lost my code when my computer crashed. Whenever I use elements of this control library, I get intellisense errors in the xaml window. When it was working, I was able to even edit it in the designer. It still builds and runs, but I heavily rely on intellisense for nearly everything in xaml, so hand-coding everything without any intellisense is really slow and difficult. Intellisense works in the C# files, it just can't find it in the xaml. The specific error it's giving me is

```
The name "RibbonWindow" does not exist in the namespace
"clr-namespace:Fluent;assembly=Fluent".
```

I get the same error for every other control used in the library. The library I'm using is the [Fluent Ribbon Control Suite.](https://fluent.codeplex.com/) I know there is a very similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108659/intellisense-not-working-when-trying-to-define-an-xmlns-in-vs2012), but the solutions there did not have any effect.

Comment: just ignore it. rebuild the project and the error will disappear after some time. unfortunately the wpf designer does not work really well :(.

Comment: I've seen that kind of thing a whole bunch in VS2010 and occasionally in VS2012. This has been happening for a few days. I've continued working on it, running cleans and rebuilds occasionally, and it's not that.

Comment: Well as I said before. I know all those bugs and most of the time all errors thrown by the designer occur without any mistakes in your code :(. I would guess, you can't do anything against it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you download the Fluent Ribbon Control Suite you need to unblock the .zip before extracting it.  To do this right click on the zip file and select 'Properties', then on the 'General' tab click 'Unblock'.

Now when you add a reference to the extracted .dll it will be able to resolve the namespace and intellisense should work.

Comment: I already had the reference in the project. I did not have to unblock it to access the DLL after extracting. If there was no reference in the project, it wouldn't even compile.

Comment: You don't have to unblock it to access the DLL. But if you don't unblock the archive before extracting it intellisense will not work on any DLL referenced from the extracted archive.

Comment: Wow, that worked perfectly! Could you explain why unblocking the _ZIP file_ somehow fixed the contained _DLL file_, because I'm stumped on how.

Comment: I'll be honest I don't really know how it works. All I know is that Windows security will block dll's from remote locations to prevent dll hijacking. This has the side effect of losing intellisense, presumably because it is trying to prevent you accessing the functions in the dll.

Comment: So Windows Security is essentially blocking parts of the DLL while it's in the ZIP, and when it's extracted, those parts of the DLL (the intellisense) are removed.